# Making the application passive, which triggered by events?

Tags: c++, events, timer

I'm studying some codes about `RS232` with `Borland C++`. The implementation of reading data from the port is polling the status of the port by timer. There are some **events** checking whether the status of the port changed. If the status changed, events trigger the data-reading subroutine.

However, I think that polling is so bad that much resource is spent on the action. Could the program be **passive in monitoring the port** without any aggressive polling or something else? In other words,

> the program hibernates unless some events which triggered by incoming
>   data in the port activate it.

Is the idea is possible?

Thank you for reading

Best regards

Answer (score 0):

I think for your requirements the design pattern named [Reactor](http://www.dre.vanderbilt.edu/~schmidt/PDF/reactor-siemens.pdf) is appropriate. Reactor is based on the system call 'select' (which is available in both Unix and Windows environments). From the referenced document,

```
Blocks awaiting events to occur on a set of Handles. It returns when it is possible to
initiate an operation on a Handle without blocking. A common demultiplexer for I/O 
events is select [1], which is an event demultiplexing system call provided by the UNIX
and Win32 OS platforms. The select call indicates which Handles can have operations 
invoked on them synchronously without blocking the application process.
```

You can see that this pattern is encoded as a library in several frameworks such as [ACE, Boost](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reactor_pattern).

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with the Win32 API functions for reading the serial port you can call ReadFile. It will suspend until it has the number of bytes you requested or until a timeout that you can set. If your program is a GUI then the serial read should be in a secondary thread so the GUI thread can react to any received Windows messages.